# Как войти в GRUB в XUbuntu, если удержание shift не помогает?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, xubuntu, recovery

Удерживаю shift - непомогает, ПК всё равно загружается в ОС. Возможно в bios как-то включить. Есть ли какие-то варианты открыть GRUB, если удерживание shift не помогает, кроме кнопки reset.

Comment: Просто взять и обновить настройки grub нужным образом через эту самую ОС, не?

Comment: @andreymal как? Мне нужен grub для сброса пароля root пользователя.

Comment: А, вот это уже правда проблема, но по-моему для этого проще загрузиться с LiveCD/LiveUSB и сбросить пароль через него)

Comment: Быстро жать `Esc` не пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata не пробовал. Это при загрузке ПК быстро жать? Это откроет grub?

Comment: @Даниил, да. Именно так.